# Вывести данные в виде исполняемого кода

Tags: python, django

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему

я через модель заполняю таблицу базы данных примерно таким html-кодом:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=m5-_plen-rNkoC6AZ8GbAd6R3pqL8dfi&amp;width=590&amp;height=270"></script>
```

затем я вывожу данные из базы данных и отображаю их в шаблоне. но у меня отображается не результат выполнения кода, а просто строка. скажите пожалуйста как отобразить именно результат выполнения кода?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

используйте фильтр [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

Answer (score 1):

Автор выше имел в виду вот такую запись в шаблоне:
    {{my_html_code|safe}}